# Use input file in \thanks{}

Tags: footnotes, titles, input

Is it possible to acheive something similar to

```
\title{\myTitle \thanks{ \input{../acknowledgement} }}
```

(which doesn't work?) in order to load the content for \thanks on the fly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume "doesn't work" means in this case "Generates the following error:"

```
! Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.8 \maketitle
```

Right?

`\thanks` expands its argument (at least which the standard classes) and so you need to `\protect` the `\input`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\myTitle{My title}

\title{\myTitle\thanks{\protect\input{../acknowledgement}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text
\end{document}
```

An alternative would be the `catchfile` package to store the content of the input file in a macro first using `\CatchFileDef{\mymacro}{<file>}{}`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you add a tiny bit about what protect does, or a link to a relevant resource? This works, but it's also really confusing :/